# How to pass a custom object to Jinja2 Template using FastAPI?

Tags: python, html, frontend, jinja2, fastapi

I am trying to pass a custom object (a `list` of `dict` in this case) to a `Jinja2Template` using FastAPI; however, it seems that it only accepts the first item from the `list`, instead of the entire `list` of items.

I'm webscraping a site and I want the data to be displayed in the frontend page (i.e., `/scrape`) in real time; however, it doesn't work, the only thing that I'm able to do is this:

**main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from scrapes.scrape_corner import C_t3
from apis.general_pages.route_homepage import general_pages_router
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import pathlib
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

BASE_DIR = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent  # app/
TEMPLATE_DIR = BASE_DIR / "templates"  # / "general_pages"

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=str(TEMPLATE_DIR))

data_t3 = C_t3()

def include_router(app):
    return app.include_router(general_pages_router)


@app.get("/scrape", status_code=200)
async def scraper():
    context = {
        "request": data_t3.scraper_t3()[0]  # HERE IS THE ISSUE 
    }
    print(context)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("general_pages/homepage.html", context)
```

As you can see I'm able to retrieve the data from the API and display it in the frontend through a Jinja2 template.

**Jinja2 template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}my title{% endblock %}</title>

</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}


    <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <p> {{ request.id }} {{ request.brand }} {{ request.availability_status }} {{ request.price }}</p>


<div style='margin-bottom:15px;'>
<p style='margin-bottom:2px;'>Campos:</p>
    {% for items in request.items() %}
     <li style='margin-bottom:2px;'><b>{{ items[0] }}</b>: {{ items[1] }}</li>

    {% endfor %}


</div>
    
{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

**The scraper**

```
import requests

class C_t3:
    @staticmethod
    def scraper_t3():
        products_list = []
        ids_list_whole = [1170046, 1191407, 1265903, 1191384]  1265903, 1191384, 1203972, 1170046, 1454790, 2065015]
        ids_list = [1988649]
        # req_prod_id = requests.get('https://cornershopapp.com/api/v2/branches/6558/products/1170046')
        for x in ids_list_whole:
            r = requests.get(f'https://cornershopapp.com/api/v2/branches/6558/products/{x}').json()
            try:
                id = r[0]['id']
            except (TypeError, IndexError):
                id = None

            try:
                availability_status = r[0]['availability_status']
            except (TypeError, IndexError):
                availability_status = None

            try:
                price = r[0]['original_price'].replace('NaN', '')
            except (AttributeError, TypeError, IndexError):
                price = None

            try:
                brand = r[0]['brand']['name']
            except (TypeError, IndexError):
                brand = None
            # print(r)
            if isinstance(id, (int, float)):
                prod_dict = {
                    'id': id,
                    'availability_status': availability_status,
                    'price': price,
                    'brand': brand,
                }

                products_list.append(prod_dict)

        return products_list


data_t3 = C_t3()
data_t3.scraper_t3()
```

The issue just starts here:

In `main.py`, I have to use `data_t3.scraper_t3()[0]` which returns the first `item` from the `list`.
If I replace the above statement with this: `data_t3.scraper_t3()`, I'm getting this error:

`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'list object' has no attribute 'items'`

And the response is this one:

```
{'request':[
        {'id': 1191407, 'availability_status': 'AVAILABLE', 'price': None, 'brand': 'Intimus'},
        {'id': 1265903, 'availability_status': 'AVAILABLE', 'price': None, 'brand': 'Intimus'},
    ]}
```

To be honest, I spent hours trying to solve this by myself, but I couldn't, and thus, I am asking for some help.

The expected result should be to be able to iterate over all items in the list  within the Jinja2 templdate, and not only the first one.

The complete project code can be found [here](https://github.com/renan-catan/fast_api/tree/main/live_scraper/backend).

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Seems like the issue is on line 9 where you try to call items[1] before your loop has reached that item. Try to just print `items` per loop

Comment: Please include relevant code and examples as text and not as images; images are hard to read (especially low contrast images like in this case) and have accessibility issues, can't be copy'n'pasted and can't be searched.

Comment: Thanks guys, as I don't know which file you're going need to check for, I added the project path from github. It's a small project, so it doesn't have much files..

Comment: Include the relevant code _in your question_; external resources can disappear at any time (and isn't searchable as part of the question) and thus reduces the value of the question for any future readers. Asking people to navigate your project without pointing to a specific file and issue will also make it harder to get a proper answer.

Comment: @MatsLindh I've posted all necessary code to reproduce the same results
in ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/scrape```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the `request` key in the Jinja2 `context` (when returning the `TemplateResponse`) to pass your own custom object. The `request` key is used to pass the `Request` object—see [`Jinja2Templates`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/#using-jinja2templates) documentation—which you should always pass as part of the key-value pairs in the `context` for Jinja2; otherwise, you would get a `ValueError: context must include a "request" key`. Hence, you should use different key-value pairs for other data that you would like to pass to the `Jinja2Template`. Example:

```py
from fastapi import Request

@app.get("/scrape")
def scraper(request: Request):
    context = {
        "request": request,
        "data": data_t3.scraper_t3()
    }
    return templates.TemplateResponse("general_pages/homepage.html", context)
```