# Cannot render a value to html from FastAPI JSONResponse with HTMX

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi, htmx

I'm making a concept of a client for API service running FastAPI. I need Fast API to serve API and HTML by different endpoints.

My FastAPI code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, JSONResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})


@app.get("/api/v1", response_class=JSONResponse)
async def api_home():
    data = {"key": "value"}
    return data
```

In this code my client pings API endpoint and gets json response:

```
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="h2">API Client</h1>
    <a hx-get="/api/v1" hx-target="#content" hx-swap="innerHTML" class="btn btn-primary">Fetch data</a>
    <div id="content">{{ key | default("No message received") }}</div>
  </div>
```

But as a result it renders:

```
{"key": "value"}
```

I need to render only `value` in my template. How to do it?

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74584131/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73440556/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using hx-get to fetch the data, assume you're using HTMX for this. You can do it with adding an hx-trigger attribute to your button to call a JavaScript function when the data is fetched. like:

`

```
<a hx-get="/api/v1" hx-trigger="fetchCompleted(xhr, 'content')" ...
...

// At the bottom of your code you may add JS code in order to update contents. 

<script>
  function fetchCompleted(xhr, targetId) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      var content = data.key || "No message received";
      document.getElementById(targetId).innerText = content;
    }
  }
</script>
```

`

here the documents for the above `https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/`

Comment: Is there any way to parse json response using Jinja2, without JavaScript?

Comment: Jinja2 is server side template engine, primarly works python objects and doesn't natively parse Json within templates.  Consider processing it in your Python code first and then pass the processed data to the template. like:
` value = json_data["key"] `
    Then pass the extracted value to the template
    `return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "value": value}) `

at the template just use `{{ value }} `